# Detect whether an flv file contains video, audio or both

Tags: flash, video, audio, streaming, flv

Is there a way to detect whether an FLV file contains video, audio or both?
The flv file is streamed to a flash client, that needs to show a certain view depending on the  data in wrapped in the flv file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FLV specs](http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf), this is indicated in the 5th byte of the file.
(Bit 2 is set if there is audio and bit 0 is set if there is video.)